# Order-preserving maps on a directed-complete poset

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

**Definitons.** A poset $P$ is *directed* if every finite subset has an upper bound in $P$. It is *directed-complete* if every directed subset has a least upper bound in $P$. For any poset $P$ let $[P\to P]$ denote the set of all order-preserving maps $P\to P$, ordered pointwise.

**Lemma.** $[P\to P]$ is directed-complete if $P$ is.

**Theorem**. Suppose $P$ is directed-complete, $f:P\to P$ order-preserving and inflationary. Then there is a unique smallest set $C\subseteq [P\to P]$ satisfying

1. $f\in C$
2. $C$ is closed under composition
3. $C$ is closed under joins of directed subsets

**Attempt of proof**. 
Let

1. $C_0 = \{f\}$
2. $C_{\alpha+1} = \{f\circ g : g\in C_\alpha\}$
3. $C_\lambda = \sup \bigcup_{\gamma<\lambda}C_\gamma$

Take $C=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON}C_\alpha$. Note that $C$ and every subset of $C$ is directed as $\sup\{f^{\alpha_1},\ldots,f^{\alpha_n}\}=\max\alpha_i$. This the supremum in 3. is always defined due to the lemma.

**Problem.** I literally only applied composition and sup so my $C$ can hardly be too big, can it? But don't I have $C=\{f^\alpha : \alpha\in ON\}$ now? But this is not a set because otherwise, by replacement, $ON$ was a set.

I think I'm a bit confused here. Can someone elucidate?

Comment: A "directed subset" of $P$ is (I guess) a set $S\subseteq P$ such that every finite subset of $S$ has an upper bound **in $S.$** Have I got that right? Also, what does "inflationary" mean?

Comment: It seems that $C_\alpha\subseteq[P\to P]$ for each $\alpha,$ right? So there is certainly going to be an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $C_\alpha=C_{\alpha+1}=C_\beta$ for all $\beta\ge\alpha.$

Comment: @bof: Inflationary: $x\le f(x)$ for all $x\in P$.

Comment: As usual, for the proof of your Theorem, as an alternative (not a better way, just an alternative) to constructing $C$ from below, you could construct it from above, as the intersection of all subsets of $[P\to P]$ satisfying the three stated conditions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. Have I forgotten the terminology since I went to school in some bygone millennium? Or is this a recent coinage?

Comment: @bof: I don’t know: I guessed it and then went hunting to confirm the guess. I don’t recall having learnt it, but I didn’t learn much of any specialized order terminology back in the 60s and 70s!

Comment: Thanks everyone! @bof: Thanks for pointing that out. But in either case I will end up with $C=\{f^\alpha : \alpha\in ON\}$, right?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have a problem. Nobody told you that doing these things will enlarge your set. At some point, your sequence is going to stabilize. Namely, there will be some $\alpha$ such that $C_\alpha=C_\beta$ for all $\beta>\alpha$.

Try and see what happens if $f=\operatorname{id}$. This understanding extends to any situation when $C_0$ is already closed under compositions and suprema.

Comment: Ahh, I see, brilliant! So $C=\{f^\alpha : \alpha\in ON\}$ is actually a valid solution?!

Comment: In fact you can show that you had necessarily stabilized somewhere before $|[P\to P]|^+$.